# What is the minimum configuration to run the JVM?

Tags: java, configuration, jvm, minimum-requirements

What is the minimum configuration to run the JVM?
The computer I work has the following settings:

`MS Windows XP Professional SP3`
`Intel Celeron 2.26GHz CPU, 959MB RAM, VIA/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP`

Using a Java-based program and I think that is causing this latency, besides having to use Internet Explorer to access the Intranet (which only allows the use of IE). So I wonder what the minimum configuration to run the JVM, so that my computer can be replaced.

From now on,
Thank you.


*Sorry for bad english*

Comment: The JVM was running on machines built before people dreamed of clock speeds measured in gigahertz; there is no real "minimum".

Comment: Definitely that computer has the _minimum specs_ to run a jvm. Java was launched when much weaker systems were being used. The slowdown depends on what your program is actually doing.

Comment: try launching an app giving it 768 mb of ram on the machine shown above :)

Comment: The "JVM" you are talking about is not the JVM we're talking about. Java 1.0 JVM is not even the same ballpark as today's Java. And anyway, a minumum is only relevant to printing "Hello, World". Everything beyond that depends on the app you are running. Eclipse is a Java app, guess what's the minimum to run it?

Comment: The smaller the computer, the harder you will have to work to get your program to fit.  IMHO its worth spending a few more $ to save yourself hours/days of work. Personally I wouldn't buy anything less than 4 GB these days, and an i3 is probably the minimum process I would buy. (In fact this is what I bought for my "TV" just to watch videos on)

Comment: What's a basic Windows box worth these days, anyway? $200?

Comment: The problem is that if I stay only in the application of the company and no longer use the computer for other purposes, yes, the system can stand quietly, but.. there are times when one has nothing to do, these are times when I check my email, enter the messenger, among other things, but I can not use it in parallel (my stuff / stuff company).

Comment: A Lenovo H330 with i3-2120 and 8 GB of memory, 1 TB HDD costs £419.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what system and what version of jdk
see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml

for Windows XP  128mb

Comment: also depends on what are you going to do with the jvm, run apps or develop them

Answer (score 0):

The more RAM the better, processor and gpu are irrelevant. My workstation has 8 GB of RAM and it's ok for running a tomcat server, database server, firefox with dev add-ons (it can sometimes use around 1 GB of ram), Eclipse and some other tools.

The more RAM you have the more you can give to the apps executed in jvm (-xmx and -xms options)

Comment: I was suspicious of memory, I think I will ask a new memory, at least 2GB. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you must consider the version of JVM you want to run, as for any other software the more you advance of version the more resources it "eats" therefore supposing you're on JVM 7
consider this table from the Oracle website

[Java System requirements](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml)

If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: as for Peter he anticipated my answer, consider this question a duplicate :)