# Java Small Utility Application

Tags: java, jvm

I am wondering about the efficiency of small Java applications.  I would like to write a small screenshot application that sits in the taskbar tray.  Since this application will be very small and always running, is it worth the overhead of having a JVM running in the background all the time?  Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: Rephrasing question: Is this an example of something that would be better written in an application that could be run natively instead of Java which requires a JVM to run?

Comment: Do you mean an application for windows?

Comment: How should we know if it's worth it? You're the one who'll be using it.

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395667/what-is-the-minimum-configuration-to-run-the-jvm

Comment: Yes, I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: Is 128MB (minimal requirements for Windows) a lot or a little for you?

Comment: I am on a powerful machine.  So I don't have any problem running a JVM.  I will rephrase the the question above.

Comment: [other JVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) may have lower memory footprint, especially if they're interpreter-only and don't have to keep compiled code in memory, although that comes at a hefty performance cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, you have to know whether it is worth it.
If you want to minimize the memory footprint of your application have a look at the guide from Oracle:
[Tuning For a Small Memory Footprint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/tune_footprint.html)